# User defined crop / crop modal for image assets

Tags: assets, image-transforms, image

Is it possible to have "user defined" crop areas (drag and crop) for upload assets of type image? What I had in mind is something exactly like craft has in the Admin > Settings > General Settings > Logo

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this myself, but the Aviary Image Editor plugin should be ideal for what you need:

https://github.com/fruitstudios/AviaryImageEditor

They also [tweeted](https://twitter.com/fruitstudios/status/573948691029102592) about the plugin with a short video of it doing exactly what you are looking for in Craft. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

This plugin is without an API, but also very handy:

https://github.com/engram-design/ImageResizer